# GetResponseAsync stuck in Scheduled status

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using below code (this is slightly simplified) to make a webrequest:

```
public async Task<string> GetResponseAsync()
{
    WebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = null;
    string content = string.Empty;

    webrequest.Method = "GET";
    webrequest.Timeout = 10000; // 10 seconds

    response = await webrequest.GetResponseAsync();//this seems to not get started

    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    response?.Close();

    return content;
}
```

This code has been working in production for months. Recently some changes have been made to the load balancer of the underlying service and now intermittently the line with GetResponseAsync gets stuck.

Below is a screenshot from the tasks debugging window. It will stay in this state for hours and the timeout does not work. The tasks window only shows tasks which are either "Awaiting" or "Scheduled". There is no task in any other state. Double clicking the task in red will go to line with GetResponseAsync method.

I feel like I might be missing something obvious here. What can be the reason of this getting stuck?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the SSL handshake failed and that the timeout does not work in this case. The solution was to pass a CancellationToken with the timeout like this:

```
await webrequest.GetResponseAsync(new CancellationTokenSource(millisecondsDelay: 10000).Token)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the link below, use ConfigureAwait to prevent deadlocks. Please read extensive doc on deadlocks due to async calls

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
  // (real-world code shouldn't use HttpClient in a using block; this is just example code)
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that code outside of this method is placing restrictions on the `ExecutionContext` or `SynchronizationContext` your task needs to resume execution.